# Devemos validar parâmetros de funções?

Tags: javascript, validação, funções, parâmetros, tipagem

Em linguagens como Java, os parâmetros de métodos são "validados" na compilação (pelo menos o tipo):

```
public void facaAlgo(String str) {
  // ...
}

// em algum outro lugar:
int i = 2;
this.facaAlgo(i); // erro de compilação!
```

Em linguagens de tipagem dinâmica, como Javascript, é recomendado validar a entrada para evitar problemas?

```
function facaAlgoComString(str) {
  if (typeof str !== 'string') {
    throw 'Está função só aceita string!';
  };
  // restante da função
}
```

Isso fica mais complexo quando se trabalha com objetos e arrays:

```
function facaAlgo(aluno) {
  if(typeof aluno !== 'object' || typeof aluno.nome !== 'string' || !Array.isArray(aluno.notas)) {
    throw 'Parâmetro incorreto!';
  }
  // ...
}

facaAlgo({nome: 'Fulano', notas: [10]}); // ok!
```

Entre os problemas de tantas validações está:

- Código poluído
- Desempenho da aplicação prejudicado

Apesar disso isto pode evitar alguns problemas.

Até que ponto ir com esta estória de validação de entrada? Existe alguma alternativa mais interessante?

Comment: Acho que você gostaria de conhecer o http://www.typescriptlang.org/

Comment: @PauloRoberto Já ouvi falar mas nunca usei. Você já utilizou? É difícil integrar com código já existente?

Comment: Sério??? Escrever código para validar tipos em uma linguagem dinâmica??? Morro e não vejo tudo. Sua pergunta faz parecer que você recebeu ou viu este tipo de recomendação. Pode passar a fonte? Eu gostaria de entender a argumentação disso.

Comment: @Caffé Não recebi esta recomendação de ninguém, mas ***eu*** me pergunto constantemente se é boa prática fazer estas validações ou não. Gostaria de ouvir mais sobre sua opinião sobre validações não serem necessárias.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Depende do que você quer. Quer ter um código organizado ou basta "funcionar"? Você pode deixar o erro acontecer no seu ponto final. Ou você pode mostrar antes onde ocorreu o erro verdadeiramente.

> Código poluído

Eu não chamaria de poluição algo que é útil. Poluição é coisa desnecessária. Se você opta por facilitar a manutenção do código, da utilização por outras pessoas ou por você no futuro. Se quer dar melhores informações para depurar, a informação no local correto é fundamental.

Na verdade esse código é até bem simples, se não for, está fazendo algo errado. É muito rápido codificar isto. Esse ínfimo gasto de tempo será compensando na primeira vez que for depurar.

#### Exceção

Não sei se a solução é usar um `throw`. Mas algum tratamento pode ser interessante. O uso de exceções não faz parte da cultura do JavaScript. Normalmente é usado em situações mais óbvias onde há um ganho fazendo desta forma. Não sei se isto está mudando ou vai mudar com aplicações cada vez mais complexas mas o fato é que não se costuma usar este recurso como é usado em outras linguagens.

E talvez seja uma coisa boa já que a maioria dos programadores usam do jeito errado. Neste caso não sei se é para uma exceção já que estamos falando de um erro de programação. O ideal é fazer algo que ajude o programador achar e entender o erro mais facilmente. Exceção não é o melhor mecanismo para isto. Eu até entendo essa confusão já que exceção em outras linguagens é usada para resolver qualquer tipo de problema, aí os programadores não entendem realmente os diversos tipos de problema.

Por outro lado se não souber o que fazer, se tratar o problema de forma errada, não adicionar informação relevante, vai adicionar código inútil mesmo.

> Desempenho da aplicação prejudicado

Primeiro que isso fará muito pouca diferença. Estamos falando de JavaScript, uma linguagem que não foi feita para ter o melhor desempenho possível.

E segundo, voltamos ao item anterior, o que é melhor para seu código? O que vai facilitar sua vida? Mesmo em outras linguagens o desempenho só deve ser uma preocupação quando você mediu e viu que há problemas, que alguma coisa está executando de forma mais lenta do que é aceitável.

Este não é um motivo para evitar esse tipo de verificação.

## Visão alternativa

Mas isso depende muito de como você e sua equipe costumam trabalhar. Se tiver um fluxo de trabalho e ferramentas adequadas, pode ser que isto não seja tão necessário. Na maioria das vezes o que você vai perder é uma melhor localização do problema. Pode ter que verificar todo o *call stack* para entender onde originou o problema.

Algumas pessoas preferem fazer isto em funções consideradas "de biblioteca" e não fazer nas funções de aplicação.

Quanto menor for a equipe e a aplicação que está fazendo, menor é a necessidade destas verificações (que eu não chamaria de validação já que isto é um problema de programação e não de entrada de dados).

## Formas alternativas

#### Testes de unidade

Outras pessoas vão dizer que é fundamental fazer testes de unidade que fazem estas verificações para você. Ou seja, a verificação é feita mas fora do código.

#### Linguagem alternativa

É possível usar alguma outra linguagem que compila para JavaScript e tem verificação de tipos em tempo de compilação. Um exemplo é o [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/).

Na verdade uma linguagem como o TypeScript trará muitas outras vantagens, principalmente se utilizar as ferramentas disponíveis para codificar nela. Ao contrário de outras linguagens que tentam rodar em cima do JS ela se comporta quase de forma autônoma. Eu nunca gostei de camadas em cima do JS mas esse caso me parece ser uma exceção. As vantagens trazidas e a quase ausência de desvantagens fazem pensar na sua utilização.

Ficaria algo assim:

```
function facaAlgo(str : string) {
  // ...
}

// em algum outro lugar:
var i = 2; // tipo de i inferido como numérico
facaAlgo(i); // erro de compilação!
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/TypeScript/Validation.ts).

## Conclusão

Enfim, é mais uma questão de gosto e adaptação ao método de trabalho. Teste por um tempo cada forma e tente encontrar a melhor alternativa para você. Eu sempre prefiro que a linguagem faça isto para mim. Depois, eu procurar ferramentas externas ao código para ajudar e só se nada disso for bom e estiver disponível eu verei se vou colocar este tipo de verificação no código quando a aplicação é um pouco mais complexa (o que não costuma ser o caso de aplicações JS para *sites*).

Recomenda minha outra resposta sobre o assunto [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43662/101).

Comment: Eu realmente não costumo ver as pessoas validando entrada em Javascript, então não sei qual seria a melhor prática ou a mais utilizada. Inicialmente `throw` me pareceu o mais natural, agora percebi que é exagero mesmo.

Answer (score 10):

Minha resposta começa com uma pergunta: **quais benefícios você vê nesta prática?**

Você listou dois pontos que considera negativo e não listou nenhum benefício.

Em JavaScript, lançar uma exceção pelo tipo do parâmetro não ser o esperado não é diferente de deixar o código estourar caso não consiga lidar com esta diferença. As ferramentas dev do Google Chrome, por exemplo, são ótimas e resolvem todos os desafios de depuração e identificação de problema em código JavaScript - você não vai depender destas validações adicionais.

Além disso, será que o tipo do parâmetro realmente será incompatível com o código do método? O JavaScript faz uma série de [conversões implícitas](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3).

O [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) oferece um paradigma ligeiramente diferente de programação e compila para JavaScript o seu código escrito neste outro paradigma. A diferença entre este framework e a validação que você sugeriu é que neste framework a tipagem fica explícita, em vez de ser trabalhosamente validada pelo programador e ficar escondida no corpo do método.

**Minha sugestão:** abrace a cultura da linguagem que você estiver usando. Você pode descobrir que seu estilo é mais adequado para resolver o que se propõe e que não é limitada mas, pelo contrário, por ter menos restrições, é muito poderosa.

Comment: Obrigado pela sua opinião! Acho que preciso repensar isso, talvez validar só em casos "extremos"

Comment: @user18612 Agora você chegou ao ponto que eu nem escrevi na minha resposta! Valide quando você souber por que está fazendo isso, em um método específico, por uma necessidade clara.

Answer (score 5):

Na verdade, o que devemos ou não fazer, cabe nós, programadores, porém o bom senso diz para que façamos validações que as vezes não estamos acostumados a fazer por saber que o Javascript é uma linguagem com tipagem muito fraca.

Por isso há algumas ferramentas para auxiliar o pessoal que visa a validação de dados, como o [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) por exemplo.

Todavia, você pode implementar uma validação por si só, assim como fizestes em sua pergunta, é cabível, pode dar trabalho no início, mas logo que todas suas funções estejam validadas corretamente, implementar novas funções e validar os parâmetros não vai ser um problema.

Como eu havia dito que o javascript é uma linguagem com tipagem fraca, ele é bem livre para que você possa trabalhar do jeito que você bem entender, muitas coisas que você não pode fazer em várias linguagens em javascript você pode (não que isso seja **lá aquelas coisas**) pois dependendo de como você escreve o código pode acabar se perdendo no meio dessa **liberdade** e tudo se tornar literalmente uma **zona** e essa é a desvantagem mais conhecida do javascript.

Bom, sabendo de tudo isso, cabe a você tomar uma decisão:

> Devo ou não validar os parâmetros de funções que eu venha a criar em javascript?

Vai de você, **mas acrescentando minha opinião**, eu diria que **sim** vale a pena validar para quem tem tempo e disponibilidade para isso, afinal o grande problema sempre é ele, o **tempo**.