# É uma boa pratica gerir sempre os erros com excepções?

Tags: python, exceção, python-3.x, pygame

Estou a criar um jogo com Python 3.4 e Pygame, e estou usando o paradigma `object-oriented`. Nas minhas classes, sobretudo nos `__init__`, estou cheio the `type checkings`, para prevenir errors de runtime. Por exemplo, esta é a minha classe `Board` (por agora), e está cheia de `exceptions handlings`:

```
class Board:
    def __init__(self, resolution, color, image_path):
        if type(resolution) != tuple or len(resolution) != 2:
            raise TypeError('incorrect format for resolution')
        if type(color) != tuple or len(color) < 3 or len(color) > 4:
            raise TypeError('incorrect format for color')
        if type(image_path) != str
            raise TypeError('image_path is not a str')

        self.resolution = resolution
        self.color = color # background color
        self.image_path = image_path        
        self.surface = pygame.display.set_mode(self.resolution)
        self.surface.fill(self.color)
    #

    def write(self, msg, color, pos, size=20, bold=False, italic=False):
        '''This function writes some text in a surface passed as parameter.'''
        if type(surface) != pygame.Surface:
            raise TypeError('surface is not pygame.Surface')
        if type(msg) != str:
            raise TypeError('msg is not a str')
        if type(color) != tuple or len(color) < 3 or len(color) > 4:
            raise TypeError('incorrect format for color')
        if type(pos) != tuple or len(pos) != 2:
            raise TypeError('incorrect format for pos')
        if type(size) != int or size < 0:
            raise TypeError('incorrect format for size')
        if type(bold) != bool:
            raise TypeError('bold is not a boolean')
        if type(italic) != bool:
            raise TypeError('italic is not a boolean')

        font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, size, bold, italic)
        text = font.render(msg, True, color)
        self.surface.blit(text, text.get_rect())
```

Gostaria de saber se fazer os `types checkings` é uma pratica comum em Python, e se, no meu caso, estou abusando deles (type checkings).

Comment: Exceções ajudam mas podem ser um praga. Eu já escrevi bastante à respeito mas nada sobre Python. Não entendo o funcionamento específico nesta linguagem mas imagino que há abuso no uso de exceções nela também. Dê uma olhada em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30168/101. Ali tem links para outras respostas que vão discutindo o assunto. Você também pode fazer buscas no *site*. Minhas respostas tendem mais para o C# e eventualmente o Java mas muito do que está nestas respostas podem ser aproveitadas. O importante é você entender que existem alternativas e o abuso sempre é ruim.

Comment: É que você não leu tudo o que eu fui *linkando*. É vai levar mais de uma hora para você ler tudo mas dá para aprender muita coisa útil. Claro que você pode pular certas partes (embora se quiser se aprofundar é melhor não fazê-lo). Eu falo sobre emissão de exceções em algumas respostas. Especialmente falo sobre o uso errado de exceções quando o problema não é um caso excepcional. Neste seu caso parece ser casos excepcionais. Também pode lhe interessar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/42603/101 )não sei qual é a cultura de Python) mas acho que os programadores também costumam preferir Unit Tests.

Comment: Em Python Tem Que Ser Assim, Como Não Existe Sobrecarga Você Sempre Vai Ter Que Testar Os Tipos Dos Parâmetros, É Normal.

Comment: "It’s easier to ask forgiveness than it is to get permission — Grace Hopper", em Python é comum o uso de exceptions, não há problemas. Em relação aos votos para fechar, não vejo essa pergunta como "principalmente baseadas em opiniões", isso não se trata apenas de "estilo de programação".

Comment: De fato, a pergunta está bem colocada, e é uma dúvida freuqente em Python: definitivametne não há razões para fecha-la a não ser que seja duplicada.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quanto a "garantir tipos" em Python como você está fazendo no código:
Em Python isso não é considerado a melhor prática.

Antes de explicar melhor o porquê é necessário entender que isso é "em geral" - não é regra: claro que há casos em que é desejável e preciso testar o tipo de dado que vem.

Mas via de regra, isso é algo que amarra seu programa a uma prática de "tipagem estática", e você joga fora uma das maiores forças da linguagem que é justamente a tipagem dinâmica.

Por exemplo, nos casos acima, você verifica se o parâmetro é do tipo "tuple", mas com uma comparação estática, pelo tipo "tuple": 
`type(resolution) != tuple`  - perceba que isso funciona se o objeto for uma "tuple" (tupla) - mas vai falhar para qualquer outro tipo de objeto. Não só outras sequências, como listas, arrays, ou objetos personalizados que você crie, mas vai falhar até mesmo para sub-classes do tipo tupla!

Veja:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>>
>>> a = namedtuple("r g b")(255,0,0)
>>> a = namedtuple("color", "r g b")(255,0,0)
>>> a
color(r=255, g=0, b=0)
>>> type(a) == tuple
False
>>> isinstance(a, tuple)
True
```

Então, **primeira coisa**: se você for fazer a checagem estática de tipo, utilize **sempre** `isinstance` e e nunca `type(variavel) == tipo` - senão você quebra justamente o paradigma de Orientação a Objetos.

**Segunda coisa**: como eu disse, em Python é melhor evitar esse tipo de checagem. Se a função vai funcionar ao receber uma lista com comprimento 3, por que jogar um "type error", só por que é uma tupla?

Como você evita que seu programa faça chamadas erradas? Daí vem a 
**terceira coisa**:  (talvez devesse ser a primeira) - **testes** - para se garantir que seu programa não faça coisas inesperadas escreva testes - tanto unitários quanto de integração. Nesse caso,  você vai pegar o tipo de erro que tem com  testes de integração: escreva funções de teste que chamem as funções que *usam* essas classes (funções que criem esses objetos seriam testes unitários) - e veja se alguma dessas quebra. Escreva testes para toda funcionalidade do programa que você completar - e pode fazer isso mesmo antes de escrever a tal funcionalidade.

E por fim, mas não menos importante: você está rabalhando com Python - uma linguagem que permite modificação em tempo de execução do comportamento de funções e classes,e uma série de outras coisas - e ficar verificando parâmetro por parâmetro com `isinstance` (ou `type(parametro) ==`) - você está realmente nadando contra a corrente.

É possível facilmente escrever um decorador para os casos acima, de forma que você possa descrever os tipos esperados numa única linha acima de cada função/método. Já que você está usando Python3, existe até mesmo uma sintaxe de anotações (annotations), pouco utilizada  que pode servir para colocar direto junto a cada parâmetro qual o tipo esperado para o mesmo - veja

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/ para a sintaxe de annotations, e 
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578528-type-checking-using-python-3x-annotations/  para uma receita de como usar as annotations para sintaxe de tipo.

Sem usar a receita, ou annotations, você também pode escrever um decorador para checagem de tipo - veja:

```
from functools import wraps
from collections import OrderedDict

class CheckTypes:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.parameters = OrderedDict(args)

    def __call__(self, func):
        @wraps(func)
        def checker(*args, **kw):
            for parameter_name, passed_arg in zip(self.parameters, args):
                self._check_parameter(parameter_name, passed_arg)
            for parameter_name, passed_arg in kw.items():
                self._check_parameter(parameter_name, passed_arg)
            return func(*args, **kw)
        return checker

    def _check_parameter(self, parameter_name, passed_arg):
        if self.parameters[parameter_name] is None:
            return
        if not isinstance(passed_arg, self.parameters[parameter_name]):
            raise TypeError("Parâmetro {} não é do tipo {}".format(
                parameter_name, self.parameters[parameter_name]))
```

O decorador com o uso de annotations fica um pouco mais complexo por conta de se ter que fazer uma introspecção na função decorara para pegar os nomes dos parâmetros passados como posicionais.  (Se bem que em Python 3.4, o módulo  `inspect` da stdlib facilitaria isso).

O decorador acima pode ser usado assim:

```
>>> class Bla:
...     @CheckTypes(("self", None), ("resolution", tuple), ("color", tuple), ("image_path", str))
...     def __init__(self, resolution, color, image_path):
...         pass
... 

>>> 
>>> Bla((),(),"")
<__main__.Bla object at 0x7f35abecf050>
>>> Bla(1,(),"")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 9, in checker
  File "<stdin>", line 20, in _check_parameter
TypeError: Parâmetro resolution não é do tipo <class 'tuple'>
```

E antes que eu esqueça -- **quarta coisa**: 
veja que sua verificação de parâmetros não melhora em nada nem o seu projeto, nem o quanto de código você tem que escrever.

Você não quer que os erros cheguem ao usuário final em tempo de execução, o que é correto. Mas qual a diferença entre

```
def minha_funcao(param1):
    if not isinstance(param1, pygame.Surface):
        raise TypeError("param1 não é do tipo Surface")
```

e

```
def minha_funcao(param1):
    pygame.draw.rect(param1, ...)
```

Observe que quando chamamos o `pygame.draw.rect` sem uma Surface no primeiro parâmetro ocorre

```
>>> pygame.draw.rect("", (255,0,0), (0,0,0,0))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: must be pygame.Surface, not str
```

Ou seja: o mesmíssimo "TypeError" - com ou sem uma checagem estática feita na sua parte do
código.  E se você não quiser que o erro chegue ao usuário final, tem que ter um "except" capturando o TypeError
da mesmíssima forma.

(E na sua função mesmo, tanto faz se o primeiro parâmetro é uma Surface "de verdade" ou
qualquer coisa que tenha os mesmas funcionalidades - para as funções internas do Pygame é que 
o objeto precisa ser uma Surface)

Comment: Apesar da resposta ser interessante me parece que você não estende bem a diferença entre checagem estática e dinâmica de tipos. Em Python só é possível fazer checagem dinâmica. É possível usar ferramentas externas, é possível fazer testes de unidade para checar se os tipos estão corretos nas situações determinadas pelos testes (e só nestas situações), mas esta checagem que pode ser considera estática não faz parte da linguagem e ela não garante nada depois disto (você até fala sobre isto). Qualquer checagem em tempo de execução será dinâmica. Ainda há mais algumas concepções questionáveis.

Comment: Ok @bigown - uso pthon há tanto tempo, que o "estático" das outras linguagensnem enmtramais na minha cabeça.  Mas de fato, onde se lê "estática"  na resposta, o correto seria "explícita" e "hardcoded".

Comment: Idealmente, você quer usar `assert isinstance(obj, type), 'error'` e não `if not isinstance(…): …`: assim, se você roda o Python com `-O`, você pode omitir essas checagens de tipo (com o `if`, você está sempre pagando o custo dessas checagens).

Answer (score 3):

Minha prática em qualquer linguagem que possui exceções é guiada por um princípio: quando o método não tem como cumprir o que seu nome promete, termine em exceção.

Mas note que isso não inclui checagem de tipos. Especialmente em uma linguagem dinâmica como Python, eu prefiro dar uma chance ao objeto que me foi passado de funcionar no meu método. Se o objeto não implementar algo que eu precise, eu automaticamente ganho uma exceção *grátis* da runtime.

Um exemplo de exceção que meu método mesmo produziria seria um `ValueError` quando eu preciso de um número maior que zero e recebo um negativo. Outro exemplo seria retornar uma exceção criada por mim, como `PermissionError` se eu determinar que o usuário não tem direito de realizar alguma operação.