# Por que validar mesmo com um valor por defeito?

Tags: php, exceção, validação, engenharia-de-software, estilo-de-codificação

Quando estou a preparar algo, por mais simples que seja, surge-me sempre a questão:

> Devo confiar no *meu* código?

Este enigma está geralmente associado ao fato de que "amanhã" posso não ser eu a dar suporte ao projeto, erros podem acontecer, e o código deve estar preparado para lidar com eles.

Pegando em exemplos simples:

- **Parametros de uma função**

  ```php
  function consultaGrupos($dbh, $limit=0) {

    if (intval($limit)>0) {
      // ...
    }

    //...
  }
  ```

  A função aceita dois parâmetros, um objeto da ligação à base de dados e um inteiro indicando que é pretendido limitar a consulta em X registos.

  O inteiro já é por padrão `0`, mas ao escrever a verificação de existência de um valor `>=1` acabo por verificar se a conversão do valor recebido para inteiro é maior que `0` assegurando que não vem por exemplo `batatas`.
- **Um valor numa matriz**

  ```php
  $moduleTitle = $this->vocabulary["text"][1];

  if (empty($moduleTitle)) {
    $moduleTitle = 'Um valor padrão...';
  }
  ```

  A entrada na matriz que contém o vocabulário existe e pela "especificação" deve estar preenchida, mas por algum motivo bizarro a mesma pode calhar de vir vazia, pelo que verificamos isso mesmo.
- **Uma propriedade de um objeto**

  Código *normal*:

  ```php
  $dbObj = consultaProduto($dbh, 1);

  if (!is_object($dbObj)) {
    // ups... não foi possível obter o produto #1
  }
  ```

  Código *extra* validado:

  ```php
  $dbObj = consultaProduto($dbh, 1);

  if (!is_object($dbObj)) {
    // ups... não foi possível obter o produto #1
  }
  else if (!property_exists($bdObj,'url') || empty($bdObj->url)) {
    // ups... não foi possível apurar o URL do produto #1
  }
  ```

  A consulta à base de dados devolve um objeto, neste exemplo uma das propriedades desse objeto de nome `url` existe sempre. Contudo, não só verificamos se obtivemos um resultado na consulta realizada como verificamos se a propriedade efetivamente existe.

  Aqui, tal como no exemplo em cima, existe também a verificação se o valor de `url` está ou não vazio.

## Pergunta

Estarei a ser demasiado protetor ao validar algo que já está assumido e contém um valor por padrão, ou de fato não devo confiar e devo validar os valores recebidos?

Comment: Esta pergunta seria o mesmo que essa outra? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42597/14584. Minha visão: partir da **não validação** (opção primária) e validar quando houver necessidade clara e uma expectativa bem definida sobre o resultado da validação.

Comment: @Caffé São realmente parecidas, apesar de que na que tu referes não vejo uma resposta ao que eu pergunto... O meu exemplo é um função, mas a pergunta visa obter o por que de se validar algo que supostamente já está definido e contém um _fallback_! Não limitado ao exemplo dado. Se relevante, posso editar e aplicar outros exemplos.

Comment: Infelizmente, com PHP você não tem tipagem de retorno então se o recurso X depende de algo retornado pelo recurso Y, então sim, você deve validar mesmo que você seja o programador mais meticuloso da equipe. Agora, no caso de um recurso vindo de um banco de dados, você pode popular uma Model pré-definida com os dados retornados, dessa forma ele sempre vai existir e do jeito correto (caso contrário não teria sido inserido, já que passaria pela mesma Model).

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Bom ponto de vista, convido-te a deixares uma resposta com o mesmo ;)

Comment: Infelizmente eu não me arriscaria porque meu conhecimento de banco de dados é bastante restrito e minhas incursões com ORM e os Design Patterns relacionados, apesar de [prontos e funcionais](https://github.com/nextframework/next/tree/dev/DB) podem ter equívocos conceituais que poderia ser danoso ao tópico.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Uma resposta definitiva não é possível. Há controvérsias sobre o que é melhor.

Vou repetir o que sempre digo e o AP sabe disso. O mais importante é padronizar o que a equipe faz e seguir sempre o mesmo padrão. O que não pode é ficar cada hora fazendo uma coisa diferente. Criar a expectativa que algo está no código e depois não estar não é bom.

## Valor *default*

Não vejo um motivo para diferenciar se o parâmetro tem um valor padrão (por defeito) ou não. Afinal se a função for chamada sem passar um argumento para este parâmetro é certo que o valor dele estará correto. **Mas se se vier um valor? Quem garante que este valor esteja correto?**

Vejo qualquer parâmetro da mesma maneira. Neste ponto acho que não há discussão.

## Verificar resultados

Depende um pouco do que será feito em seguida, mas em geral, acho que o ideal é verificar se está tudo ok com o resultado. Porque se não estiver você poderá ter um resultado inesperado.

A pergunta diz que existe uma especificação dizendo que não pode ter um valor vazio. Tudo que é especificado deve ir para o código de alguma forma.

A não ser que tenha um claro e bom motivo para não colocar.

Quanto mais próximo da especificação, melhor. E quando mais precisa, mais localizada for a identificação do erro, melhor também.

A grande questão é se é possível gerar um resultado inesperado e principalmente indesejado se a informação não for exatamente a que você acha que deve obter.

Em códigos robustos é primordial que não faça nada com dados duvidosos.

Considere inclusive analisar se esta verificação não pode ser feita dentro da função que está chamando e gerando o resultado em questão. Não são só os parâmetros que devemos verificar, o retorno da função também pode ser verificado antes de encerrar a função e tomar uma ação mais apropriada quando se sabe que vai retornar algo que não será útil.

Claro que colocar esta verificação dentro da função implica nela ficar mais específica. Pode ser que você tenha os dois usos. Ainda assim considere ter duas versões da função, uma que permite, por exemplo, retornar vazio e outra que impede este retorno.

## Verificar argumentos antes de passá-los

É útil para informar melhor onde está o erro. Em geral agrega pouca informação fazer esta verificação antes. Em tese a função deve indicar bem que houve um problema na sua chamada.

Mas existe uma exceção onde a validação é fundamental. Há casos em que um argumento pode ser válido para aquele parâmetro (o mesmo vale para um índice de um *array* que não deixa de ser um argumento) mas naquela situação específica um determinado valor naquele momento pode não ser adequado, pode trazer resultados inesperados se ele for usado. É algo que só o programador ali na hora sabe que pode haver problema em usar aquele valor.

Fica óbvio que é um caso para verificar antes se ele está dentro da necessidade.

Alguns poderão dizer que no fundo isso é uma variação do caso anterior onde o valor já é verificado logo quando ele é recebido como retorno de uma função (ou operação qualquer que retorne algum valor).

## O que está fazendo?

Depende um pouco do tipo de código que está sendo produzido.

Vou descartar um *script* simples de provável duração curta, de acordo com a descrição da pergunta. Também vou considerar apenas as premissas colocadas na pergunta. Desconsiderarei o caso do programador ser único no projeto (que eu responderia de forma diferente).

#### Biblioteca

Está fazendo uma biblioteca genérica que será usada por outros pessoas? É quase certo que deveria verificar e dar a melhor informação possível para o usuário da função saber o que ele fez errado.

Não consigo ver outra forma para garantir o uso da função de biblioteca corretamente sem fazer isso. Especialmente em PHP.

Há um custo de performance em verificar, mas ele normalmente é ínfimo. Quase nunca faz diferença, e se fizer provavelmente é melhor fazer esta função em outra linguagem e expor ao PHP. Portanto não vou considerar a performance um argumento para não colocar uma verificação tão importante.

#### Código de aplicação

De uma certa forma códigos que serão usados por várias pessoas em tempo prolongado, mesmo que seja código específico do aplicativo, não deixa de se comportar como um código de biblioteca.

Então a decisão se deve validar ou não passa pela cultura das pessoas envolvidas no projeto.

Se você não pode garantir quem serão estas pessoas ou sabe que elas não são sistemáticas e/ou não costumam usar outras formas de verificação de código, a resposta mais óbvia é fazer a verificação.

Você só pode ter certeza que a função será usada corretamente se fizer a verificação.

## Testes externos

Hoje há a ideia de que a verificação deve ser feita por testes externos. É uma boa ideia, mas isto só garante a verificação se alguém fizer o teste corretamente no código consumidor.

O teste de uma função de forma isolada só consegue testar o que está internamente nela, o que ela tem controle. Então é possível testar o que ela faz e o valor *default* que ela recebe (você tem controle sobre este valor).

Os testes da função só poderão verificar situações simuladas de uso dela. É possível testar o comportamento da função em determinadas situações, em determinados valores recebidos.

Há o entendimento que raramente você testará 100% das situações. Isto por si só deve questionar se o teste isoladamente é solução efetiva.

Mas vamos considerar que o teste cobriu 100% das situações. Isto apenas mostra o que a função executará em caso de uso indevido. Ele não evita o uso indevido.

Para garantir que não tenha uso indevido você terá que testar o uso da função. E estes testes deverão ser feitos no código consumidor da função se baseando na documentação dela.

Haverá disciplina e entendimento total para que isso sempre seja feito e obtenha um resultado satisfatório?

Mesmo que isso seja possível, vale à pena?

Testar todos os códigos consumidores **dá muito mais trabalho** que testar apenas uma vez no código produtor do resultado desejado.

E mais, é garantido que ele sempre será executado corretamente (desde que tenha sido escrito corretamente). **Testes não garantem nada**.

Claro que testes perfeitos podem garantir, mas quem garante que eles são perfeitos?

Neste momento me parece que valer-se apenas dos testes um pouco ingênuo e nada produtivo.

## Em toda função é necessário verificar os parâmetros?

Em acho que é uma questão de consistência. Mas compreendo quem ache que alguns casos é desnecessário.

Se o parâmetro serve imediatamente de argumento para outra função que fará uma verificação provavelmente não trará maiores problemas. É um caso em que a economia de código de verificação pode ser justificada.

Claro que você pode acabar em uma sequência enorme de funções que não verificam parâmetros delegando para a função chamada seguinte.

A única grande desvantagem é que o erro ocorrerá em um nível superior da pilha de chamadas indicando que o erro ocorreu em um local que pode estar distante da verdadeira fonte do problema obrigando o programador precorrer todo o *stack trace* e olhando a documentação de todas as funções da cadeia de chamadas para achar onde está o erro.

Com a verificação em todas as funções você sempre terá a informação na real origem do problema simplificando a depuração manual (no olhômetro) ou através de uma ferramenta, poupando tempo do usuário da função.

Apesar das funções do PHP serem documentadas os programadores vivem passando dados errados para elas. Imagine se não tivesse nenhuma verificação e ele assumisse um valor qualquer, como pioraria a situação. De fato algumas funções fazem isso e é uma das coisas mais criticadas no PHP.

Vamos dizer que você coloque um nome expressivo no parâmetro para mostrar o que pode ou não pode passar (não que isto garanta alguma coisa). Que nome você escolheria para indicar que precisa ser um valor numérico que não pode ser negativo? E se for uma faixa mais estrita de valores? E se tiver algumas faixas? O nome do parâmetro deve conter informação sobre a regra dele? E se mudar a regra? Este seria o pior caso de notação húngara que eu já vi.

Claro, você pode confiar na documentação escrita e que ela será seguida. Isso não dá robustez, simplesmente não dá. Você pode confiar ou não, esta é uma decisão sua e obviamente você não quer que ninguém decida por você. Aqui apenas tem algumas informações para ajudar a decidir.

## O que fazer

Uma função deve impedir seu funcionamento ou resolver um problema sempre que um parâmetro esteja impróprio para uso.

## O que pode acontecer de errado?

Se não tiver uma verificação, não tiver um teste perfeito que detecte um argumento passado errado, a linguagem não ter uma forma de verificar tudo o que seja necessário e o código consumidor chamar a função com argumento errado, ela executará de forma errada, possivelmente produzindo um resultado inesperado.

O "possivelmente" pode parecer um atenuador mas na verdade é um agravante. Pode passar a falsa sensação de confiabilidade em algumas situações.

Por sorte em alguns casos o problema será tão grave e tão constante que o programador logo perceberá o erro.

Quer contar com a sorte em seu código?

Ainda assim pode ser que ele não tenha a melhor informação possível acerca do problema.

Mas o que acontece com frequência é que a função executa normalmente sem apresentar erros aparentes. Apenas dá um resultado diferente do esperado. E pode ficar assim, sem ninguém perceber por anos, causando prejuízos.

O mesmo vale para a continuidade de códigos que dependam de retornos de funções.

Eu não vi o resto do código nos exemplos postados mas muito provavelmente algum erro sutil acontecerá se retirar as verificações. E provavelmente você e as pessoas que foram mexer com isso terão uma perda de tempo considerável para descobrir o que está acontecendo.

Novamente, se der sorte o erro será catastrófico logo de cara e perda de tempo será pequena.

## Se precisar tirar essa verificação, o que fazer?

Se for imprescindível que a verificação seja removida do código, provavelmente por performance, documente muito bem como a função deve ser usada e como testar seu uso. Se possível crie uma ferramenta que ajude testá-la.

Neste caso você pode delegar a verificar para o código consumidor onde a verificação seja feita em um ponto que não afete a performance.

## Conclusão

Particularmente, na situação descrita (fazer para futuros programadores) não é exagero fazer todo tipo de verificação possível. Na dúvida, verifique. Nunca é inútil evitar que o programador use algo de forma errada.

Uma boa recomendação seria: se você pode provar que um dado ruim não causará nenhum problema, não verifique.

Nesta situação um dos maiores perigos é achar que os programadores vão usar tudo certinho sempre e não vão cometer deslizes que não serão facilmente detectados. Aqui mesmo no SOpt vemos todos os dias programadores cometerem erros bobos e não conseguirem achar o problema muitas vezes porque o código não deixa ele óbvio. Convenções não ajudam muito achar erros.

Você não aprendeu que sempre deve validar o que o usuário faz? Por mais absurdo que possa ser o dado ele sempre pode acontecer. Pois bem, estamos falando de validar o que um usuário está fazendo. No caso o usuário é o programador que usa o código que você fez. Por que deveríamos tratar programadores como super-humanos que não cometem erros?

Em PHP qualquer parâmetro pode vir qualquer coisa, não importa se ele tem um valor *default* ou não. Então é preciso verificar o que vem.

É o que eu costumo dizer em diversas respostas minhas. A regra serve para orientar, mas existem muitas regras. Quando aplicar a correta nem sempre é fácil saber. É preciso experiência e principalmente não se apegar com unhas e dentes à uma delas. Entenda o contexto antes de aplicar uma regra. Não acredite cegamente no que leu em um livro porque ele não sabe o seu contexto.

#### Outras linguagens

Somente em linguagens que tem mais controle em compilação sobre o conteúdo que pode ser usado durante o consumo da função é que dá para relaxar **algumas** verificações mas não todas. Algumas linguagens podem evitar a necessidade de verificar tipos ou se um valor é nulo. Outras mais sofisticadas podem até ter uma assinatura que podem ser usadas em tempo de compilação para analisar a característica do valor e decidir se ele é aceitável. Mas note que no fundo você escreverá uma verificação também mesmo que a sintaxe simplifique isso.

#### Quando evitar

Você pode evitar a verificação nos casos em que tenha certeza (de verdade) que um dado errado produzirá resultado adequado também. Há casos, por exemplo, que retornar um vazio tem uma semântica adequada. O resto do código saberá como se comportar com isso, poderá até ter um efeito colateral desejável.

Outra possibilidade é querer assumir o risco. Confiar que todos lerão a documentação, farão todos os testes perfeitos e quando isso não ocorrer não vai causar grande problema. Não é uma recomendação, apenas uma constatação.

E é claro que se a situação for outra, se você tem total controle sobre a aplicação, se o código não for feito para outras pessoas utilizarem ou dar manutenção, então você pode relaxar um pouco mais. O problema é saber quanto dá para fazer isso sem se comprometer negativamente.

#### Referência adicional

Eu falo mais sobre isso [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/42603/101). Especialmente sobe verificação de tipos onde normalmente é menos necessário verificar em algumas linguagens. Há uma tendência de erros de tipos causarem um problema muito visível. Claro que linguagem com *casting* automático mal pensado aumenta o risco.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Eu continuo lendo muito texto aprovando a validação generalizada de tipos de parâmetros e mesmo com tanto texto não aparece o básico: quais os benefícios da validação generalizada? Pode dar alguns exemplos do que pode acontecer sem a validação generalizada e de como ficaria melhor com ela?

Comment: Entendo a recomendação pró-validação, mas lendo as suas duas respostas ainda não entendi se você é favorável a sempre validar os *tipos* dos argumentos (no caso dessas perguntas, em PHP e JS). Porque se for pra sempre validar tipo nessas linguagens, não seria melhor partir de uma vez para uma linguagem com tipagem mais rígida?

Comment: Tipos eu acho que não é interessante fazer sempre. Mas depende do que está fazendo. Se for uma biblioteca eu acho que deve fazer sempre sim. Não seria melhor "optar" por uma linguagem estática de todas as situações por pelo menos duas razões: 1) como você vai optar por linguagem estática para rodar no *browser*? Se você só sabe uma linguagem ou só pode usar aquela, não tem escolha, a maioria das pessoas não escolhem PHP 2) Linguagem estática não permite várias construções flexíveis que uma dinâmica permite, não é só questão de verificar tipo em compilação ou não.

Comment: Mas você tem um pouco de razão. A questão aí é que as linguagens dinâmicas são usadas quando o programador tem controle sobre tudo o que ele está fazendo, tem uma equipe muito coesa, há muito disciplina na programação ou quando não se exige robustez. Mas se quer algo robusto tem que verificar tudo mesmo. Como eu falei, em alguns casos até dá para deixar para a última função chamada verificar o tipo. Não tem dá uma informação certeira sobre o erro mas não causa maiores problemas. O seu caso é diferente da pergunta aqui. Você tem controle sobre todo o software.

Answer (score 3):

## Precisamos de código mais significativo em vez de mais código

Quando o código é bem expressivo, é mais fácil para os programadores saberem o que esperar dele. Isso diminui o medo que nos leva a adicionar mais e mais código em busca de robustez - o que geralmente é uma tarefa ingrata pois por mais que validemos, nunca validaremos o suficiente.

Quando o **C#** (como sabemos, uma linguagem que nasceu como estaticamente tipada) introduziu o **var** houve uma ampla discussão - para muitos, quando usado para declarar tipos não anônimos isso diminuiria a legibilidade do código. Um exemplo de um destes argumentadores era que

```
List<ContaaPagar> contasVencidas = contasaPagar.ObtemContasVencidas();
```

era mais expressivo que:

```
var contasVencidas = contasaPagar.ObtemContasVencidas();
```

Então um contra-argumentador questionou: o que mais pode ser retornado por **contasaPagar.ObtemContasVencidas()** do que uma lista de contas a pagar? Uma lista de sacos de batata? E, num contexto de contas a pagar, o que mais pode residir numa variável **contasVencidas** além de uma lista de contas a pagar vencidas?

É claro que se o primeiro argumentador tivesse mostrado um exemplo como este:

```
List<ContaaPagar> cts = ctPg.getVenc();
```

todos iriam concordar que, neste caso, explicitar o tipo da variável cai muito bem (só não cai melhor do que refatorar este código feio).

Este foi só um exemplo, trazido de uma linguagem que nasceu fortemente e estaticamente tipada, para demonstrar que o mais importante é que o **nosso** código seja expressivo.

Vou entrar em cada um dos exemplos na pergunta.

### Exemplo 1 - Validar tipo do parâmetro

```
function consultaGrupos($dbh, $limit=0) {

    // se $limit contém outra coisa que não um inteiro,
    //  lança uma exceção.
}
```

A assinatura desta função, dependendo do contexto e da cultura do projeto, até que já está bem expressiva. Mas só para garantir, vamos reescrevê-la:

```
function obtemGrupos($contextoDb, $qtdMaximaResultados=0)
```

O que mais esta função pode retornar e o que mais eu posso passar para ela além do que já foi deixado óbvio na assinatura? Quais são as chances de alguém passar "batatas" no segundo parâmetro? Vale a pena lançar uma outra exceção além da exceção padrão que o PHP vai lançar quando ele tentar usar "batatas" como se fosse um inteiro?

É claro que eu estou considerando que "Grupo" é um termo de negócio muito bem definido e não ambíguo no contexto.

### Exemplo 2 - Validar existência de um item em um dicionário

```
$moduleTitle = $this->vocabulary["text"][1];

if (empty($moduleTitle)) {
  $moduleTitle = 'Um valor padrão...';
}
```

Se eu compreendi o contexto, isto não é apenas uma validação - trata-se de uma regra de negócio que admite que nem todos os itens necessários podem estar presentes, e que se não estiverem o aplicativo continua a funcionar com um valor padrão. É claro que provavelmente você iria querer encapsular isto em uma função de modo a poder reutilizar esta checagem em vez de repetir o código todas as vezes. Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
obtemPrimeiroSinonimo($texto) {

    $primeiroSinonimo = $this->vocabulario[$texto][1];
    
    if (empty($primeiroSinonimo)) {
        $primeiroSinonimo = 'Um valor padrão...';
    }
}
```

Veja que mais uma vez eu considerei que existe algum conhecimento do contexto por parte do programador, e que o código expressa bem este contexto de modo que o próprio código ajuda no aprendizado do programador.

### Exemplo 3 - Validar uma propriedade de um objeto recebido de uma função

```
$dbObj = consultaProduto($dbh, 1);

if (!is_object($dbObj)) {
  // ups... não foi possível obter o produto #1
}
else if (!property_exists($bdObj,'url') || empty($bdObj->url)) {
  // ups... não foi possível apurar o URL do produto #1
}
```

Esta segunda validação está correta dependendo da modelagem da solução ou do sistema como um todo. Um exemplo de quando ela está correta: **url** não é um atributo obrigatório do produto, esta consulta acontece na hora de tentar criar um link pra ele, e é esperado pelo negócio que um produto sem url simplesmente fique sem um link nesta visualização em particular. Observe então que não se trata de uma validação apenas, mas sim de um fluxo previsto pelo negócio, e o que houve não é um "não foi possível apurar" mas sim um "este produto simplesmente não tem url e é um direito dele, por isso eu verifiquei".

A primeira validação também está correta se um teste automatizado (fui um pouco mais longe agora) demonstra que o comportamento esperado de **consultaProduto** é retornar "nada" se não houver produto disponível. Mas, mais uma vez, não se trata de um "não foi possível obter" mas sim um "não existe produto aqui pra você". Por fim, seria melhor, em vez de retornar "nada", retornar uma lista vazia já que a assinatura do método sugere uma lista como retorno.

O que não está correto aí é a expressividade do código: **dbObj** dificilmente é um termo de negócio e este nome não tem nenhum valor para um humano.

## Conclusão

- Escrevemos validações para tratar exceções previstas pelo negócio. Este é o melhor motivo para escrever uma validação.
- Escrevemos validações quando não conseguimos ser suficientemente claros na API do nosso framework ou biblioteca e sabemos que os consumidores, por não entender como utilizar, vão utilizar errado. Então a mensagem de erro da validação explica o que falhamos em deixar auto-explicado pela API.
- Escrevemos validações quando não temos testes automatizados para validar e explicar os comportamentos menos óbveis do nosso sistema.
- **Não escrevemos validações genéricas sem compreender muito bem o motivo**, ou seja, sem compreender o que de mal poderia acontecer sem a validação e de que maneira ela está ajudando a prevenir o problema. Por que não fazemos isso? O principal motivo é evitar o desperdício de escrever código potencialmente inútil e que pode até atrapalhar.

Answer (score 0):

Em minha opinião, independentemente se já há valor padrão definido ou não para o parâmetro na função exposta, vejo sua validação como algo bom. Na verdade, quase excelente, uma vez que estamos falando de uma linguagem de programação em que não nos preocupamos com tipos de variáveis. Enfim, não vejo isso como demasia, e sim com uma ótima preocupação.

Comment: E quais os benefícios dessa validação? Quero dizer, pode listar alguns efeitos práticos positivos?

Comment: O benefício está exatamente no que o amigo @bigown falou aí acima. PHP é uma liguagem fracamente tipada, isso significa que em parâmetros de funções podem vir absolutamente qualquer coisa. Ou seja, o maior benefício é você garantir que seu código funcione como você espera que ele funcione. Além disso, exatamente por manter estas validações, outros programadores poderão manter seu código de forma mais coerente, afinal, sabe-se que determinado método ou função só funcionará de tal jeito. Enfim, mais validações, menos exceções.

Comment: O problema é que o @bigown também não listou nenhum benefício ainda. Como a validação generalizada garante que "seu código funcione como você espera que ele funcione"?

Comment: O benefício é exatamente esse, garantir que seu código funcione como você espera. No exemplo você espera que o valor do parâmetro seja um inteiro, se não for inteiro, ele não entra na condição e não faz nada. Está funcionando do jeito que você espera? Não. É uma validação generalizada, mas ela serve de apoio pra você e para outros programadores. Como eu disse, mais validações menos exceções.

Comment: Aprimorei a pergunta com mais exemplos de forma a não estarmos limitados ao exemplo dado de uma função, mas sim concentrados na pergunta em si e no motivo pelo qual devemos validar mesmo sabendo que "de trás" já vem algo por padrão.