# Por que definir uma constante para o mesmo documento e checar se ela existe no próprio documento?

Tags: php, estilo-de-codificação, constantes

Vejo em muitos códigos por ai programadores que *setam* uma constante e no próprio documento verificam se essa constante existe (foi definida) nele próprio. Gostaria de saber o porque disso acontecer.

Quando baixamos o código aberto da plataforma de fóruns [phpBB3](https://download.phpbb.com/pub/release/3.1/3.1.2/), e abrirmos o arquivo `install/database_update.php`, logo nas primeiras linhas notamos isso:

```
if (defined('IN_PHPBB') && defined('IN_INSTALL'))
{
    $updates_to_version = UPDATES_TO_VERSION;
    $debug_from_version = DEBUG_FROM_VERSION;
    $oldest_from_version = OLDEST_FROM_VERSION;

    return;
}

define('IN_PHPBB', true);
define('IN_INSTALL', true);
```

Em quase todos os arquivos encontrados para download no código do `phpBB3`, existe essa constante `define('IN_PHPBB', true);` sendo definida no inicio do código.

Esse é o principal exemplo que consigo lembrar para elucidar minha dúvida.

Com base nesse código (e alguns outros que vi por ai, mas não vou ter a mão), existe algum motivo em especial para isso? É algum tipo de boa prática de segurança?

Comment: Eu diria que se o `define` e o `if` estão no mesmo ficheiro não faz muito sentido. Mas quando temos "includes" e essas linhas estão em ficheiros diferentes então é uma boa prática. Dê uma olhada a uma pergunta parecida: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43650/129

Comment: Você poderia *linkar* alguns exemplos para mostrar um contexto.

Comment: @bigown, eu tenho "à mão" aqui apenas o exemplo do phpBB3, apesar de já ter visto em outros lugares isso.. Tentei elucidar melhor minha questão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É difícil dizer ao certo qual a intenção de terceiros se não tem nenhuma documentação. Uma resposta precisa só poderia ser dada por quem fez. Eu posso dizer porque eu faria alguma assim... se fizesse ou porque eu acho que teria em um código.

## Programação defensiva

Pode parecer estranho mas e se um dia partes do código forem separadas, quem separar vai perceber que precisaria verificar a existência? É o mesmo princípio de usar chaves mesmo em blocos de uma linha. O dia que precisar aumentar uma linha não precisa se preocupar.

## Extensões

Uma variação da primeira razão. No caso o PHPBB é um software conhecido por contar com um sistema de extensões que muitas vezes altera o código fonte principal. Então faz sentido verificar porque uma extensão pode criar algum problema.

## Legado

Estava em dois fontes e eles foram mesclados e não teria porque refatorar demais. Foi mais fácil deixar assim. Isto acontece especialmente quando vários programadores trabalham no mesmo código. Isto pode ter acontecido inclusive porque um fonte foi criado por gerador de código e depois mesclado. É uma chance menos provável nas é possível.

## O programador está perdido

Nunca descarto essa possibilidade. Mas sempre fico mais com a primeira e secundariamente com a segunda.