# Qual é o papel dos parâmetros?

Tags: terminologia, parâmetros

Sei o conceito de `função` e `procedimentos`, mas estou com um pouco de dificuldade em entender o **papel dos parâmetros**.

Comment: "Para que servem os parâmetros", é isso que você quis dizer? Misturando com o termo matemático ficou um pouco ambíguo...

Comment: Por função dos parâmetros você quis dizer "papel dos parâmetros" ou algo assim?

Comment: [Entendendo parâmetros e argumentos em funções](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/175434/91) e [Qual a diferença entre parâmetro e argumento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/91)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parametrizar informações, tornar genérico algo que seria específico, dar variabilidade para um algoritmo com dados externos desconhecidos naquele local, é para estabelecer um ponto de comunicação entre o algoritmo local e o algoritmo externo.

O parâmetro é uma variável local como outra qualquer, pelo menos na maioria das linguagens ou todas *mainstream*, cujo valor será conhecido apenas na chamada da função. Então a atribuição do seu valor é sempre feita em tempo de execução, salvo alguma otimização que consiga eliminar isto.

Ele tem [escopo, tempo de vida e visibilidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) local, então só existe dentro da função, enquanto ela está sendo executada. A única diferença para a variável é o momento da atribuição do valor que ocorre na chamada e não dentro da função.

Note que o parâmetro existe na função, ao contrário da chamada onde se passa um [argumento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101). Um argumento já pode ser qualquer expressão válida na maioria dos casos. Pode ser uma variável, um literal, uma expressão com fórmulas, etc. Mas tem argumentos que precisam ser variáveis , aí depende de tipagem.

Em geral [parâmetros precisam ser validados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42597/101) já que o valor recebido pode não ser adequado ao que se propõe o algoritmo. Mas depende da linguagem, da disciplina de tipagem, do estilo de programação.

Passar parâmetros tem custo e não deve ser abusado. Cada um deles há um cópia de dados, mesmo os tipos por referência precisa copiar o endereço do ponteiro.

O abuso pode se dar também do ponto de vista de organização. Fica muito complicado administrar funções com muitos parâmetros.

Assim como pode-se receber parâmetros ([dicionário](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/par%C3%A2metro)) pode-se comunicar saindo da função com o retorno dela. Geralmente pode ter apenas um retorno, ainda que algumas linguagens usam tuplas implícitas ou explícitas para retornar mais de um dado. A comunicação na saída pode ocorrer por um parâmetro também, desde que ele seja uma referência e permita que o dado seja modificado, então entra com uma valor e quando termina isto está com outro valor. Obviamente que isto só será útil na chamada se for uma variável.

Isto pode ser útil: [O que acontece quando chamamos uma função?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/170372/101)

Comment: Uma expressão lambda `v((x) -> x.y > 0)` ou uma função anonima `v(fun(p) { })` pode ser considerado um argumento?

Comment: Sim, qualquer coisa que pode ser passada para a função é um argumento. Lambdas são funções, provavelmente de [primeira classe.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227485/101). No caso o parâmetro será uma referência para a função da *lambda* e ela poderá ser chamada normalmente.

Comment: Então os parâmetro é como se fosse uma variável que só será lida e modificada em uma sub-rotina?

Comment: @OrdasIvarov sim, ela é uma variável local que só existe ali dentro.